# How to access QuickBooks company file with QuickBooks Integrated Application in QuickBooks Server mode installation?

Tags: quickbooks

I have installed QuickBooks Enterprise Solutions 14.0 R3 (non licensed Server version) in our Server. Installed with option “I will NOT be using QuickBooks on this computer. I will be storing our company file here so it can be shared over our network. (A license is not required for this option)”. 
QuickBooks Enterprise Solutions 14.0 R3 installed in other computers in our network uses the QuickBooks company file.

Our QuickBooks Integrated Application

- Microsoft Dot Net WPF windows application that uses QuickBooks SDK 13.0.
- Uses QBFC to connect QuickBooks Company file and pull and push data.
- Our Integrated Application acts as a service which will listen for incoming request (from another Client application) and respond to the request (fetch/ push data to QuickBooks company file).

Our QuickBooks Integrated application works fine with full installation of QuickBooks Enterprise Solutions 14.0 R3. I’m aware that any Integrated Application should be registered with the company file and should get the access granted to read/ write data to QuickBooks company file. But, In QuickBooks Server mode installation, I was unable to register or connect to QuickBooks company file.

Is it NOT possible to connect to the company file from Integrated Application without installing full QuickBooks Enterprise Solutions in Server computer?, which we use only to share the QuickBooks Company file over our network and don’t use QuickBooks Application.

Doesn’t QuickBooks Database Server Manager will help the Integrated Applications to connect to the QuickBooks Company file? If NOT, Is there a workaround to use the Integrated Application with QuickBooks Company file without installing the full QuickBooks Enterprise Solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it NOT possible to connect to the company file from Integrated Application without installing full QuickBooks Enterprise Solutions in Server computer?,

You must have the full version of QuickBooks installed on the computer running the integrated application.

> Doesn’t QuickBooks Database Server Manager will help the Integrated Applications to connect to the QuickBooks Company file?

No. QuickBooks Database Server Manager does absolutely nothing related to integrated applications.

> If NOT, Is there a workaround to use the Integrated Application with QuickBooks Company file without installing the full QuickBooks Enterprise Solutions?

No.

Either run the integrated app on another computer that has the full-blown QuickBooks install on it, or install the full QuickBooks app wherever your integrated app is.

Remember that QuickBooks licensing is *not* per-computer. It is per-concurrent-user-of-a-given-QuickBooks-company-database.

So, you can have QuickBooks installed on 1,000 computers even if you only have a 5-user license. You just can't have more than 5 concurrent users of any given QuickBooks company file.